# <img src> not working with google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, image-load

hi i m not able to load an image in chrome using    *img src="E:\pic1.jpeg"*   when i run this code in internet explorer its working bt not in chrome . on the other hand when i give the name of image instead of path in src then its working ...

plz help ... regards Prabjot

Comment: You realize that using a windows-style absolute `d:\path\file` is not going to work on a published website?  No one in the world but you is likely to have that file in the exact same place.

Comment: Following up with what @Marc B said: upload your image to an image hoster like http://tinypic.com/ for example, and use it's new internet url instead. This will fix the Chrome image problem.

Comment: Refer this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348326/img-tag-path-not-working-in-chrome-and-firefox/7348419#7348419

Answer (score 1):

Chrome probably doesn't handle file system paths (or at least not without using file://). Even if this did work, that link would only work on your local machine as the person browsing your website wouldn't have an image at that location.

You should be using URLs for your resources (i.e. images), not file paths.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using file:// to prefix your image local path?

Comment: For example change E:\pic1.jpeg to file://E:/pic1.jpeg