# Img tag path not working in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, image

I am using MVC3 Razor and I want to load an image from the local drive for the testing purpose.

I wrote the img tag like:

```
<img id="ImgEmployee" src="file://D:/Photos/14.jpg" alt="Employee" />
```

It is working with IE. But in Chrome and Firefox it is not getting loaded.

How to set the path for img tag which loads the image from the local drive and works in all browsers?

Comment: Why don't you put a folder on your site file tree with all your imagens and point to there?

Comment: The images will be pasted in the particular folder and the image name will be there in database. I need to load these images dynamically..

Comment: Try store the images on a relative path that points to that folder. Check the other answers below for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome and FireFox expect 3 `/` characters:

```
<img id="ImgEmployee" src="file:///D:/Photos/14.jpg" alt="Employee" />
```

<strike>If you put only 1 `/` they should be able to guess, but if you put 2 it'll think you mean 2.</strike>

If you omit the `file:///` the browsers will guess that is the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML page is also on your local drive, you can do relative linking. Say your HTML file & image is in the same folder, you just use:

```
<img id="ImgEmployee" src="14.jpg" alt="Employee" />
```

Explanation: This is a security setting of your browser, so webpages cannot load resources from your computer without your consent.

Comment: The security settings you're referring to do not impact images.

Answer (score 1):

Do not give absolute path to the image, use relative path means like this :

If your html file located in `c:\project_folder` and your images located in

`c:\project_folder\Photos` then use following image tag

```
<img id="ImgEmployee" src="Photos/14.jpg" alt="Employee" />
```

Comment: OP should not have to restructure his file arrangements to accommodate a relative naming scheme, especially since the capability to use absolute paths is still available.

Answer (score 1):

It works when i moved the image folder(Photos) under the solution folder structure(Without including into the solution also).

`<img id="ImgEmployee" src="../../Content/Photos/14.jpg" alt="2" />`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having src="../../Content/Photos/14.jpg" try "~/content/Photos/14/jpg"  the "~/" will point to the root of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I've just tried:

`src="Content/images/photo.png"`

on server side. And it works.

In your case:

```
<img id="ImgEmployee" src="Photos/14.jpg" alt="Employee" />
```

Answer (score 0):

we can get answer for this in two ways

first way: just copy the file path(image saved in your any desktop folder ) and copy in src attribute ,after copied remove extra double quotes on both side and it should be below like this

note1: after this make sure that , dont go with open live server, you have to go with run a file in command prompt...

note2: In command prompt you just give command like   start fileName(index.html)
[command prompt command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbDMl.png)

Method2:
just copy the image path and paste it in  src attribute of img tag like below

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpqY7.png)

and open the file structure of html code and click on chrome icon just like below
[to get output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PGuw.png)

finally get the image on ui by following any of the above method.....